# UITablviewCell UIWebView play video issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, video, iframe, uiwebview

what i need to do is create an tableview , with cells in it; and a UIWebview inside tabelviewCell,whitch means that i got tableviewcells and i need them to load html video(src like : http://v.qq.com/iframe/player.html?vid=w0330g8iova&tiny=0&auto=0);

the question is : when i play the video , i can't play another one, if i click other cell to play video,  the playing video stop;

it seem like cells are the same one, and i post my code here:

```
- (void)loadHTMLStringWithDict:(NSDictionary *)tempDict {

if ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"scene"]) {
    _videoWebView.hidden = NO;
    _videoWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    _videoWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _videoWebView.opaque = NO;
    _videoWebView.delegate = self;
    _videoWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _videoWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    _videoWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    _videoWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

    NSString *head = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"video_iframe\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" margin=0 padding=0 src=\""];
    NSString *foot = @"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen = 0></iframe>";
    NSString *imageHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", head,[tempDict objectForKey:@"src"],foot];

    imageHTML = [CommonTool HTMLStringAddImgStyleWithOriginal:imageHTML];

    _videoWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;
    [_videoWebView loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];
}
}
```

i run this method in 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

i have been worked for this issue for 2 days, welcome for any advice....

thanks for watching.....

Comment: @Luo Hua Chu: which framework you are using to play the video ???

Comment: @AmitSrivastava no framework, i use UIWebView to load html, and i belive that uiwebview will use MPMovieplayer to play videos, because the Play interface just like MPMoviePlayer;